# SQL how to add up the totals of the same data value

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have this table

```
|      status      |    month       |      years       |
|                  |                |                  |
|      resign      |     jan        |        2019      |
|      resign      |     jan        |        2019      |
|       Stay       |     feb        |        2019      |
|      resign      |     feb        |        2019      |
```

I want to sum total status with the same value and by month&years

The result should be this

```
|      resign      |    month       |        years     |
|         2        |     jan        |        2019      |
|         1        |     feb        |        2019      |
```

Comment: There is no reason to shout at us :)

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, use a case expression to count resigns.

Comment: If you add (Stay, mar, 2019) to your sample data, do you want 0 for March, or should the March row not be in the result?

Comment: @jarlh i want to be 0 for march

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
select count(`status`) as `resign`, `month`, `years`
from t1 
where `status` = 'resign'
group by `month`, `status`, `years` ;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gTTjUEPyynJciKx2DbypKY/8